# Print variable views template

Tags: 8

I have created a view with table format but i am not able to print field variables in twig template of **view** suppose machine name of eck field is **field_large**,**field_quote_source** and so on.

```
 <ul class="bxslider">
  {% for row in rows %}
<li{{ row.attributes }}>
  {% for key, column in row.columns %}
        {% for content in column.content %}
          {{- content.separator }}{{ content.field_output -}}
          {{ content.field_large }}
        {% endfor %}                  
  {% endfor %}
</li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the path for accessing single fields in a view table template, for example in the first row:

```
rows.0.columns.fieldname.content.0.field_output
```

In your code example, to get all field names available, use this in the first loop:

```
{{ dump(row.columns|keys) }}
```

The naming of the fields depends on how you have configured the view and is not necessarily the machine name of the field in the entity.

Comment: Thank you so much ,but what is the logic behind this ,our drupal 8 concept is not so clear ,can you suggest me some tutorial links

Comment: Can you put the above line of code into loop ,again i am stucked

Comment: This line is only to show where you can find the field names. If you really want to work on this view template use xdebug, why and how to use xdebug is described in the official documentation https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates